# Method Not being found even though it is there

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

I have a web application that is written using this stack: PostgreSql/Asp.net/Mono/C#. 
I have a FormView on my .aspx page. I am using C# to fill and work with the FormView rather than a (sqldatasource) control. Therefore I am also using C# for the "Update" command as well. For the most part things are working but now I am getting this error and I don't understand what I am missing.

> Method 'sbmanager.cm.frcmFormView_ItemUpdating' not found.

On my FormView on the .aspx I have this entry:

```
    <asp:FormView id="frmcm"  
              AllowPaging="true"  
              runat="server" 
              DataKeyNames="CustomerId" 
              AutoPostBack="true"
              OnItemCommand="fmCmCd"
              OnPageIndexChanging="frcmPageIndexChange"
              ViewStateMode="Enabled"   
              OnItemUpdating="frcmFormView_ItemUpdating"
              OnModeChanging="frcmFormView_ModeChanging"
              DefaultMode="ReadOnly"
                        >
```

and in my behind code I have this:

```
public void frcmFormView_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    { frmcm.DataBind(); }
```

I also want to added I used this as my example but still same problem:
[FormView.ItemUpdating Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.itemupdating(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What is sbmnager.cm? Can yo share the entire line of code where you are attaching the event?

Comment: sbmanager is the project name. I also added the formview events. Thanks!

Comment: Code behind class of the form is cm.aspx.cs? Can you share the inheritd and code behind attribute values of your form.

Comment: Are you sure the namespace of the form matches the code-behind?

Comment: Yes the Code behind is cm.aspx.cs.   Yes the code behind namespace is matching, The thing that is odd is,  other functions are working for example FormViewModeEvent and FormViewCommandEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using a FormView. I just wrote my own form scratch. After doing that everything is working. Particularly with the dev stack I am using its seems the less controls formview, gridview, sqldatasource i use he less problems I run into.